# Loop over a Pandas series to generate Dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas

Hi I have a pandas series that I like to loop over to generate a certain JSON format (dic).

My code

```
strategy = {}
for ticker in buy_tickers:
    item = {"ticker": buy_tickers.index[ticker]}
    for i in buy_tickers:
        values = [{"rebalancedWeight" : buy_tickers[i]}]
    item.append(values)
    strategy.append(item)
```

buy_tickers data

```
AXS      0.1667
FET      0.1667
LUNA     0.1667
POLY     0.1667
QNT      0.1667
STEEM    0.1667
Name: 2021-07-29 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

strategy Expected output

```
{
"ticker": "AXS",
"values": [
{
"rebalancedWeight": 0.1667
}
]},
{
"ticker": "FET",
"values": [
{
"rebalancedWeight": 0.1667
}
]}.....
```

Error

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

When I check buy_tickers.index[0] I get "AXS"

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
import io

data = '''s    val
AXS      0.1667
FET      0.2667
LUNA     0.4
POLY     0.65
QNT      0.22
STEEM    0.11'''
buy_tickers = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' \s+', engine='python')
buy_tickers.set_index('s', inplace=True)

strategy = []
for i, ticker in enumerate(buy_tickers.index.tolist()):
    # print(i, ticker)
    d = {"ticker": ticker, "values": [{"rebalancedWeight" : buy_tickers['val'].loc[buy_tickers.index[i]]}]}
    strategy.append(d)

Output:

[{'ticker': 'AXS', 'values': [{'rebalancedWeight': 0.1667}]},
 {'ticker': 'FET', 'values': [{'rebalancedWeight': 0.2667}]},
 {'ticker': 'LUNA', 'values': [{'rebalancedWeight': 0.4}]},
 {'ticker': 'POLY', 'values': [{'rebalancedWeight': 0.65}]},
 {'ticker': 'QNT', 'values': [{'rebalancedWeight': 0.22}]},
 {'ticker': 'STEEM', 'values': [{'rebalancedWeight': 0.11}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is the "val" for in the dataset? Can it not be done with my current Pd series?

Comment: I used s and val as index and column names., respectively. If your column name is rebalancedWeight, use that instead of val.

Comment: Cool thank you, just one last thing I realized. The JSON format is dic (ending { }) while the output you are giving is a list (I'm aware in my code I create an empty list). It seems that dic doesn't have append